# How can android app sell any content?

Tags: android

I have Android App, that connect to my own server with images, and users can download selected images. I want add function for users pay for my content in app, and download only after payment, via webmoney or plastic card. How can i make it? Which library can i use?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why try make your own version when Android has a more native way described below.

Part of `Google services`, there is `Google Play In-app Billing` API, which will give you the functionality you require to have people pay for content in your app.

Have a further read into `consumable items` which basically is items in your app that can be purchased more than one.

Below is a direct link for further information:
http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html